# Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got "tuple"

Tags: function, merge, module, terraform, amazon-rds

I'm getting the below error which I'd appreciate some help with. I'm trying to add a bolt-on to a terraform public module to apply a best practice set of options in addition to any passed to the module in the usual way. What's the correct way of doing this please as I'm not certain that nesting my lookup function within a merge is valid.

```
terraform version = 1.1.12
provider version = hashicorp/aws 2.49
```

**error message**

```html
│ Error: Error in function call
│ 
│   on ../modules/db_option_group/main.tf line 5, in locals:
│    5:   merged_options = merge(var.mysql_standard_options,var.options)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.mysql_standard_options is tuple with 1 element
│     │ var.options is empty tuple
│ 
│ Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got "tuple".
```

**main.tf snippet**

```html
locals {
  name        = var.use_name_prefix ? null : var.name
  name_prefix = var.use_name_prefix ? "${var.name}-" : null
  merged_options = merge(lookup(var.option_group_map,var.engine_name),var.options) # error caused here
  description = coalesce(var.option_group_description, format("%s option group", var.name))
}

resource "aws_db_option_group" "this" {
  count = var.create ? 1 : 0

  name                     = local.name
  name_prefix              = local.name_prefix
  option_group_description = local.description
  engine_name              = var.engine_name
  major_engine_version     = var.major_engine_version

  dynamic "option" {
    # for_each = var.options
    for_each = local.merged_options
    content {
      option_name                    = option.value.option_name
      port                           = lookup(option.value, "port", null)
      version                        = lookup(option.value, "version", null)
      db_security_group_memberships  = lookup(option.value, "db_security_group_memberships", null)
      vpc_security_group_memberships = lookup(option.value, "vpc_security_group_memberships", null)

      dynamic "option_settings" {
        for_each = lookup(option.value, "option_settings", [])
        content {
          name  = lookup(option_settings.value, "name", null)
          value = lookup(option_settings.value, "value", null)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**variables.tf snippet**

```html
variable "options" {
  description = "A list of Options to apply"
  type        = any
  default     = []
}

variable "option_group_map" {
  type = map
  default = {
    "mysql" = "var.mysql_standard_options"
    "mariadb" = "var.mysql_standard_options"
    "sqlserver-ee" = "var.sqlserver_standard_options"
    "sqlserver-ex" = "var.sqlserver_standard_options"
    "sqlserver-se" = "var.sqlserver_standard_options"
    "sqlserver-web" = "var.sqlserver_standard_options"
    "oracle-ee" = "var.oracle_standard_options"
    "oracle-se2" = "var.oracle_standard_options"
  }
}

variable "mysql_standard_options" {
  description = "A list of DB options to apply for MySQL instances"
  type        = any
  default     = [
                   {
                      # For auditing of connection attempts.
                      option_name = "MARIADB_AUDIT_PLUGIN"

                      option_settings = [
                         {
                            name = "SERVER_AUDIT_EVENTS"
                            value = "CONNECT,QUERY_DDL"
                         },
                         {
                            name = "SERVER_AUDIT_FILE_ROTATIONS"
                            value = "35"
                         }
                      ]
                   }
               ]
}
...
...
...
```

** --UPDATE 1-- **

I changed the brackets used from square brackets used for lists/tuples to curly braces in my variable definitions like so:

```html
variable "options" {
  description = "A list of Options to apply"
  type        = any
  default     = {}
}

variable "option_group_map" {
  type = map
  default = {
    "mysql" = "var.mysql_standard_options"
    "mariadb" = "var.mysql_standard_options"
    "sqlserver-ee" = "var.sqlserver_standard_options"
    "sqlserver-ex" = "var.sqlserver_standard_options"
    "sqlserver-se" = "var.sqlserver_standard_options"
    "sqlserver-web" = "var.sqlserver_standard_options"
    "oracle-ee" = "var.oracle_standard_options"
    "oracle-se2" = "var.oracle_standard_options"
  }
}

variable "mysql_standard_options" {
  description = "A list of DB options to apply for MySQL instances"
  type        = any
  default     = {
                   option1 = {
                      # For auditing of connection attempts.
                      option_name = "MARIADB_AUDIT_PLUGIN"

                      option_settings = {
                         option_setting_1a = {
                            name = "SERVER_AUDIT_EVENTS"
                            value = "CONNECT,QUERY_DDL"
                         },
                         option_setting_1b = {
                            name = "SERVER_AUDIT_FILE_ROTATIONS"
                            value = "35"
                         }
                      }
                   },
               }
}
```

But still look to be getting issues with both variables passed to the merge function. Am now thinking maybe I need a for loop for this.

```html
│ Error: Error in function call
│ 
│   on ../modules/db_option_group/main.tf line 4, in locals:
│    4:   merged_options = merge(lookup(var.option_group_map,var.engine_name),var.options)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.engine_name is "mysql"
│     │ var.option_group_map is map of string with 8 elements
│     │ var.options is empty tuple
│ 
│ Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got "string".
```

** --UPDATE 2-- **
If I add the "..." onto the end of the variable within the merge and remove the lookup it looks better I just need to work out a way to conditionally use a different variable depending upon the engine type.

```html
-- from main.tf
  #merged_options = merge(lookup(var.option_group_map,var.engine_name),var.options...)
merged_options = merge(var.mysql_standard_options,var.options...)
```

** --UPDATE 3-- **
Ok think I've sorted now by splitting up the option group blocks per engine type and amending the count type rather than doing a lookup

```html
locals {
  name        = var.use_name_prefix ? null : var.name
  name_prefix = var.use_name_prefix ? "${var.name}-" : null
  merged_mysql_options = merge(var.mysql_standard_options,var.options...)
  merged_postgres_options = merge(var.mysql_standard_options,var.options...)
  merged_sqlserver_options = merge(var.mysql_standard_options,var.options...)
  merged_oracle_options = merge(var.mysql_standard_options,var.options...)
  description = coalesce(var.option_group_description, format("%s option group", var.name))
  mysql_option = length(regexall(".*mysql*", var.engine_name)) > 0
  postgres_option = length(regexall(".*postgres*", var.engine_name)) > 0
  sqlserver_option = length(regexall(".*sqlserver*", var.engine_name)) > 0
  oracle_option = length(regexall(".*oracle*", var.engine_name)) > 0
}

resource "aws_db_option_group" "mysql" {
  count = var.create && local.mysql_option ? 1 : 0

  name                     = local.name
  name_prefix              = local.name_prefix
  option_group_description = local.description
  engine_name              = var.engine_name
  major_engine_version     = var.major_engine_version

  dynamic "option" {
    # for_each = var.options
    for_each = local.merged_mysql_options
    content {
      option_name                    = option.value.option_name
      port                           = lookup(option.value, "port", null)
      version                        = lookup(option.value, "version", null)
      db_security_group_memberships  = lookup(option.value, "db_security_group_memberships", null)
      vpc_security_group_memberships = lookup(option.value, "vpc_security_group_memberships", null)

      dynamic "option_settings" {
        for_each = lookup(option.value, "option_settings", [])
        content {
          name  = lookup(option_settings.value, "name", null)
          value = lookup(option_settings.value, "value", null)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      "Name" = var.name
    },
  )

  timeouts {
    delete = lookup(var.timeouts, "delete", null)
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Comment: The first thing I don't think will work is assigning a value inside of the `option_group_map` variable by using another variable.

Comment: Yep I wasn't sure that was valid either maybe i need a for loop